# .Net 8 Blazor Web App how to map nonexisting urls to <NotFound> element

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

This is an Interactive WebAssembly Blazor Web app.

When user click a link which a nonexisting url, I want the app goes the `<NotFound>` Element setup in the `<Router>`:

The link like this:

```
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link px-3" href="not-found">
        <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Not Found
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

The router like this:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
       <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>

    <NotFound>
        <div>Not found</div>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

The server-side `Program.cs` is like this:

```
 builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
     .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

 ...

 app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
     .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
     .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly);
```

The problem now is, when clicking such a link, the application just refresh, and then browser go to default 404 not found.

I like to handle this by the app, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem encountered, and there is a solution.

Let the **UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects** in your program handle it.

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/not-found")
app.run();
```

[image]
[image]

There is a same discussion about this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48983